# Exporting server settings in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: netbeans, server, wildfly

I have server `wildfly-9.0.1.Final` installed into my NetBeans IDE - I'm deploying there my application. I have configured it (set start options, default location etc.).

My problem is - how to export those server settings in a way that I could silently import them into another NetBeans instance? I mean to copy all settings under `Tools -> Servers` with my `WildFly server`.

Where are those files located on local filesystem? I couldn't find them in my `userdir` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer and I bet that somebody will find this useful for him.

Those settings are stored in `userdir` directory, under those locations:

1. `config/J2EE/jb.properties`
2. `config/J2EE/InstalledServers/instance`
3. `config/J2EE/InstalledServers/.nbattrs` - important, here are settings, arguments etc.
4. `config/Modules/.nbattrs`
5. `config/Modules/org-netbeans-modules-javaee-wildfly.xml`

Just simply copy/create those files into new `userdir` directory and your server instance will copy aswell.

Comment: Nice! Note, that I had to add one server manually first (just entered any values). Otherwise the servers would not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't those exported when you save your NetBeans settings ?

Comment: Can you say something more about this? Can I export only selected settings or all of them at once? I'm asking, because I need to configure automated configuration of environment and I would rather copy only settings that are really needed instead of all of them - I would let users have what they like.

Comment: Use the Export and select Miscellaneous->Java EE